# So Function? Do I use it?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a refresh button that has this code on it. I would like my spreadsheets to refresh no matter what when I click on the refresh button even if there is an error of =REF! which in my code I say to evaluate some of my sheets and if there is a =REF! to be done and if there is no =REF! then to record the i3 and i4 into my data sheet.

```
Sub logs()

Dim Sht As Worksheet
Dim checkRange As Range, CheckCell As Range

For Each Sht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
With Sht
    Select Case .Name
        Case "Final Four", "Top Left", "Bottom Left", "Top Right", "Bottom Right"
            Set checkRange = .Range("A1:Z100") ' set the range for the current sheet

            For Each CheckCell In checkRange
                If IsError(CheckCell) Then If CheckCell = CVErr(2023) Then Exit Sub
                Next CheckCell

        Case Else
            ' do nothing

    End Select
End With
Next Sht

ActiveSheet.EnableCalculation = True

lst = Sheets("data").UsedRange.Rows.Count
x = lst + 1

    ' Display a message when one of the designated cells has been
    ' changed.
    ' Place your code here.
    Sheets("data").Range("A" & x) = ActiveSheet.Range("I3")
    Sheets("data").Range("B" & x) = ActiveSheet.Range("I4")


End Sub
```

Comment: Am I correct to understand that instead exiting the sub as the code shows now, you want evaluate the offending cell on the fly and then retest it?

Comment: I would like the code to refresh my data no matter what is happening in my workbook if I click on the refresh button

Comment: so @pnuts ? Do You get it? :D